# Git push failed, no error

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, push

When I wanted to push my changes i got error:

```
Failed with error: unable to read askpass response from 'C:\Users\Ernesto\.IntelliJIdea2017.3\system\tmp\intellij-git-askpass.bat' failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1) could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error
```

I reinstalled git, but it did not help. Some guys in web, suggest reinstall Intellij as well, but will I loose my changes?

Anyone had it before?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ uses a custom script to prompt the user for a password in GUI and pass it to command-line git. Seems something affects the script execution (e.g antivirus, or maybe some JVM issue). IDE log should have more details, actually.
See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150555

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Intellij helped, maybe it's not the best solution but worked for me, commit stayed.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @chade_helped a lot